# Validate presence of associations in a many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

In my Rails app I have a many-to-many relationship between 2 models `Teacher` and `Course` through a join table. I'd like to create some sort of validation where a course can't be created without being associated to at least one teacher (it is assumed that all teachers are in the database by the time we are adding a new course). This would be easy to do if this was a one-to-many relationship, but with a many-to-many relationship, we need to save the `course` before we can associate it with `teachers`.

My initial plan was to override Rails `create` method in the `Course` model to allow passing `teacher_ids` and validate presence of at least one `teacher_id` before saving the `course`, but I'm not sure this is a nice approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write [custom validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations), which is quite easy (please adapt to your code):

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers

  validate :has_one_teacher_at_least

  def has_one_teacher_at_least
    if teachers.empty?
      errors.add(:teachers, "need one teacher at least")
    end
  end
end
```

That way, you'll only be able to create courses if associated to one teacher like so:

```
teacher = Teacher.create()
course = Course.new()
course.teachers << teacher
course.save!
```

Comment: This validation will always fail creation of a course, because the course will not have any teachers when it's first created.

Comment: `I'd like to create some sort of validation where a course can't be created without being associated to at least one teacher`

Isn't that what you want? Your question is unclear then.

Comment: Oh, I guess you think you can only `create` records. `create` actually is `new` + `save!`.

Create a `new` instance, associate some teachers, then `save!` it.

Comment: you can do that? I thought `new` instance doesn't have `id` until it's saved and thus cannot be referenced by another record until it is saved.

Comment: Why would you need the Course `id`? I don't get it.

Comment: to associate a `course` record to a `teacher` record in the join table of the database, you need course's id. I don't think Rails gives you the `id` of a new record until that record is saved.

Comment: No you don't need the `id`. As I said,you can use new, set the association then save the object, Rails will handle all association the magic:
```ruby
# given you have a teacher
course = Course.new() ; 
course.teachers << teacher ;
course.save!
```

Note: this requires of course all the `has_and_belongs_to_many` to be set (both models).

Comment: you are right. Please update the main answer with this, and I'll set it as accepted.